# Mountain Lion -- Finder always freezing

Tags: macos, finder, performance, cpu

I'm on 10.8.2.  Finder always freezes.  I have way more CPU and memory than this OS needs.  It's only Finder.  CPU usage spikes, spinning beachball, the whole thing.  I cleared all my caches, disabled the "all my files" finder window.  What else can I do?  Does this get fixed in 10.8.3,4, or 5?

Comment: anything of interest in console logs ?

Comment: Getting ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Drive/GoogleDriveIpcPipe is a symbolic link ... cannot connect socket to server.

Comment: What about the Google drive? do you use the web version or have it installed on your Mac.

Comment: I have it installed.  I suppose I ought to uninstall it?

Comment: Yes, I removed it and only use the web version.

Comment: Whew, what a relief.  Now I get to enjoy my system resources again!

Comment: nice, glad it worked for you. here are some + points as reward :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling Google Drive and restarting the Finder has solved this issue.